# What's moment calibration?

Tags: regression, calibration

I read the following in [Google's Rules of ML](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/rules-of-ml/#rule_14_starting_with_an_interpretable_model_makes_debugging_easier):

> In **linear,** **logistic,** or **Poisson** regression, there are **subsets of the data** where the average predicted expectation equals the average label (**1-moment calibrated,** or just calibrated). This is true assuming that you have no regularization and that your algorithm has converged, and it is approximately true in general.

What's "1-moment calibrated"

Comment: The answer to (1) is in the quotation itself.  ("1-moment" is just an unusual synonym for "arithmetic mean.")

Comment: Thanks @whuber - If I understand what you are saying correctly, "1-moment calibrated" simply means that the average value of our predictions matches the true average value of the parameter in the data. So e.g. if we are predicting a class in classification, the average class we would predict (under the distribution of input features) would match the average label in the data. Is that what you mean?